# Unique value in set in table

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I'm having a table with three columns: UserId TeamId IsTeamCaptain. How can I make sure that there's only one 'true' value in the IsTeamCaptain column per TeamId? So let's say I have five different UserId's all belonging to TeamId 1, then in those five there can only be one 'true', the rest must be 'false'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **Unique Filtered Index** on the Set(Filtered Index is introduced in **SQL Server 2008**)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
        [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [TeamID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [IsTeamCaptain] [bit] NOT NULL)
go

create trigger triu_SampleTable on SampleTable
instead of insert, update
as
begin
set nocount on

declare @userid int, @teamid int, @isteamcaptain bit, @counter int

declare cur cursor local fast_forward for
select userid, teamid, isteamcaptain from inserted

open cur

fetch next from cur into @userid, @teamid, @isteamcaptain
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
if @isteamcaptain = 0
    insert into Sampletable(userid, teamid, isteamcaptain)
    values(@userid, @teamid, @isteamcaptain)
if @isteamcaptain = 1
    if exists(select * from SampleTable Where teamid = @teamid and isteamcaptain = 1)
        raiserror('Not allow to add more than 1 captain per team',16,1)
    else 
        insert into Sampletable(userid, teamid, isteamcaptain)
        values(@userid, @teamid, @isteamcaptain)

fetch next from cur into @userid, @teamid, @isteamcaptain
end

close cur
deallocate cur

end
Go
```

it's a trigger on our table

Comment: UNIQUE Constraint on the field IsTeamCaptain does not allow to create more than one entry with the same value of the field IsTeamCaptain.

Comment: Ah, I see. But doesn't this make it so that it can't have more than one 'false' value per team?

Comment: I would have made a trigger like this

Comment: I would strongly avoid using cursors in triggers.

Comment: may be necessary to be afraid of cursors in triggers, but if you insert multiple rows into a table, the trigger without the cursor can work incorrectly